# Python Issue after Windows 10 Update

Tags: python, windows, jupyter-notebook

I'm going to make this question as succinct and to the point as possible. I have a jupyter notebook that worked perfectly yesterday. Today, my windows 10 machine demanded an update and after updating, the jupyter notebook now cannot run. I can import libraries and define functions, but when I actually go about using the libraries and functions for computations, the [*] denoting python is busy never goes away, meaning the code is stuck (or is super slow). Even after 20 minutes the first code cell is not carried out. Yesterday, this notebook would run all 40 (roughly) cells in seconds. I have no idea why this happened, where to start trouble shooting from, or who to turn to for support. Has anyone else encountered this issue?

Windows: 10 (Version: 1607, OS Build: 14393)
Python: Anaconda (Python 3.5)
Architecture: 64 bit
Jupyter Notebook File + Resorces: https://github.com/diggetybo/ICA-Attachments

Comment: How can we know how does Python perform in your PC without codes, without versions, without configs & diagnostic information.

Comment: I'll do my best, bear in mind I'm not an advanced user, I'll put what I know at the bottom of the post.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the windows update meant well, but it created a lot of upheaval on my system. I had to reconfigure a lot of settings ranging from privacy to monitor display resolution. I believe some registry entries are different, although I typically don't look registry entries on a day to day basis. Some registry switcharoo is my best guess as to why Python suffered from the update.

Good news is I got it functional again by reinstalling anaconda. It was a time consuming and desperate approach to the problem. At someone's leisure, any technical explanations as to why this might have occurred could still be worth posting. I'm hoping I won't have to do this every windows update.

I'd like to exempt myself from user error, but I'm not sure whether others have this problem or not. Please share any similar experiences in the comments.

Thanks for reading.